# Invert-range operation in a circular vector

Tags: c++, performance, algorithm, vectors, circular-list

I implemented a *invert-range* operation in a (logical) circular vector. A circular vector is a vector without a logical starting and ending object, or, equivalently, the successive element of the element at the last index of the vector is the element at index 0 (similarly for the previous element).

I'm not 100% sure it's correct. If it's correct, any suggestions to improve it (especially in terms of performance)?

```
#include <cmath>

...

vector<SomeObject> vec;

...

/*
 * Invert the segment starting at object at index i and ending at object at index j.
 * */
void invert(const int i, const int j) {

    // assert i and j are in the bounds

    if (vec.size() < 2 || i == j) {
        return;
    }

    int segment_size;

    if(j < i ){
        segment_size = std::ceil(((vec.size() - i) + j) / 2.0);
    } else {
        segment_size = std::ceil(std::abs(j - i) / 2.0);
    }

    for (int x = 0, k = i, w = j; x < segment_size; ++x) {
        std::swap(vec[k], vec[w]);
        k = next(k);
        w = previous(w);
    }

}
```

where `next` and `previous` are the following procedures:

```
/*
 * Returns the index to the object after the object at index i.
 * */
int next(const int i) {
    return (i + 1) % vec.size();
}

/*
 * Returns the index to the object before the object at index i.
 * */
int previous(const int i) {
    return (i - 1) % vec.size();
}
```

Note: these functions were actually methods, i.e. part of a class, and they actually working on a field and not on, e.g., global variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Bug

Your `previous()` function doesn't wrap around well:

```
int previous(const int i) {
    return (i - 1) % vec.size();
}
```

When `i` reaches 0, this function will return `-1`, not `vec.size() - 1` as you might be expecting.  You could either go with:

```
int previous(const int i) {
    return (i - 1 + vec.size()) % vec.size();
}
```

or perhaps:

```
int previous(const int i) {
    if (i == 0)
        return vec.size() - 1;
    return i - 1;
}
```

#### Unnecessary use of float

The *Floating Point Police™* disapprove of your unnecessary use of floating point here:

> ```
> if(j < i ){
>     segment_size = std::ceil(((vec.size() - i) + j) / 2.0);
> } else {
>     segment_size = std::ceil(std::abs(j - i) / 2.0);
> }
> ```

All you are doing is rounding up, so you could just do:

```
if(j < i ){
    segment_size = (vec.size() - i) + j;
} else {
    segment_size = j - i;
}
segment_size = (segment_size + 1) / 2;
```

Technically, there could be a problem with the above if your segment size can be `INT_MAX`.  If this is possible, then replace that last line with this instead:

```
segment_size = (segment_size / 2) + (segment_size & 1);
```

But if your segment size could be `INT_MAX`, then your `next()` function would need to be fixed as well.